# Create Microsoft Excel SumIf Function on List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I need to write a generic extension method for `List<T>` that conditionally considers several  `Textbox` value(10 of them) to see if each of them is under 25, then `Sum` another set of `Textbox` values if a condition is met.

same as `SUMIF` in Microsoft Excel where (range(textbox array1), criteria(=<25), sum of the range(textbox array2). =SUMIF(F7,"<=25",I10)+SUMIF(L13,"<=25",L20)

I used the following code from another thread, I just don't know how to implemented on click of button.

```
public static double SumIf<T>(
      IEnumerable<T> source,
      Func<T, double > textSelector,
      Func<T, double> valueSelector)
{
    return source.Where(x => textSelector(x) <= 25.5).Sum(valueSelector);
}
```

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are asking (at least to me) in regards to the 2 lists

Comment: What do you mean? Surely you would call `SumIf` from the button click handler?

Comment: Is this a WPF application?

Comment: Are there any cases where the `textSelector` and `valueSelector` are expected to be different? If not, you should do `source.Select(textSelector).Where(x => x <= 25.5).Sum();` Also, what is `targetText` used for?

Comment: You are writing the extension method on IList, but this would only work for list of textboxes? Why dont you use Zip to combine the two list and return the sumif on this combined one

Comment: I have 2 sets of textboxes, if the value of each textbox in first set is smaller or equal to 25, sum up the values of the second textbox sets. just like SUMIF in excel

Comment: check the following thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754502/extension-method-sumif-on-generic-listt

Comment: It's really not clear where your problem lies. Add a button, add an event on "Click", write code to pass the values from your textboxes to this method, etc. Note my suggestion is still very general because we don't know what UI framework you're using (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, MVC, etc.) or where the problem in implementing is.

Comment: To clarify: there doesn't seem to be any issue with your `SumIf` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed `SumIf` method is a little awkward for your purposes.

Let's assume that you have managed to define two arrays of text boxes - the first set that you are checking if the value is below 25 and the other that you want to sum:

```
TextBox[] firstTextBoxes = ...;
TextBox[] otherTextBoxes = ...;
```

Now for me to use your existing `SumIf` method I need to call it like this:

```
double result =
    Ex.SumIf(
        firstTextBoxes.Zip(otherTextBoxes, (first, other) => new { first, other }),
        x => double.Parse(x.first.Text),
        x => double.Parse(x.other.Text));
```

The `Zip` pairs up the text boxes and then you can call `SumIf` on the paired list.

The way that the code is written it just hides some of the logic inside `SumIf` and has very little interesting code remaining to tell you whats going in.

Your code is hard to understand.

One approach is to change `SumIf` to `SumOtherIfFirstLessThanEqual25` like this:

```
public static double SumOtherIfFirstLessThanEqual25(IEnumerable<(TextBox first, TextBox other)> source)
{
    return source.Where(x => double.Parse(x.first.Text) <= 25.0).Sum(x => double.Parse(x.other.Text));
}
```

Now you can write:

```
double result =
    Ex.SumOtherIfFirstLessThanEqual25(
        firstTextBoxes.Zip(otherTextBoxes, (first, other) => (first, other)));
```

Now, if you turn `SumOtherIfFirstLessThanEqual25` into an extension method:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static double SumOtherIfFirstLessThanEqual25(this IEnumerable<(TextBox first, TextBox other)> source)
    {
        return source.Where(x => double.Parse(x.first.Text) <= 25.0).Sum(x => double.Parse(x.other.Text));
    }
}
```

...you can write this:

```
double result =
    firstTextBoxes
        .Zip(otherTextBoxes, (first, other) => (first, other))
        .SumOtherIfFirstLessThanEqual25();
```

That's readable and you can understand what's going on.

However, it's better to stick with a more standard approach.

You could write your `SumIf` method like this:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static double SumIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, bool> filter,
        Func<T, double> selector)
    {
        return source.Where(x => filter(x)).Sum(selector);
    }
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
double result =
    Ex1.SumIf(
        firstTextBoxes.Zip(otherTextBoxes, (tb, otb) => new { tb, otb }),
        x => double.Parse(x.tb.Text) <= 25.0,
        x => double.Parse(x.otb.Text));
```

This is better, and generally contains all of the logic in the right spot. But it can still be made better if you get rid of the `SumIf` method entirely.

Try this:

```
double result =
    firstTextBoxes
        .Zip(otherTextBoxes, (tb, otb) => new { tb, otb })
        .Where(x => double.Parse(x.tb.Text) <= 25.0)
        .Sum(x => double.Parse(x.otb.Text));
```

This has all of the same functionality, but the logic is built up using standard LINQ operators and it is clearly stepped through and easy to read.

Now you just need to write this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] firstTextBoxes = /* populate your first array here */;
    TextBox[] otherTextBoxes = /* populate your other array here */;

    double result =
        firstTextBoxes
            .Zip(otherTextBoxes, (tb, otb) => new { tb, otb })
            .Where(x => double.Parse(x.tb.Text) <= 25.0)
            .Sum(x => double.Parse(x.otb.Text));

    //do something with `result` here
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I expected as a result, it's more clear now, thanks a lot for introducing different method and sorry for not being clear